# Change entries in dropdown list (Customer Title/Prefix list items)

Tags: magento2.4, dropdown-attribute

We set up a Magento 2 shop. There are forms for customers to fill out e.g. register in the shop. In the dropdown menu for **Name Prefix**, I can see some entries for the user to choose.

Where can I change these Name prefix dropdown entries?

[image: How to change Name Prefix list items]

Comment: Is it Magento Open Source or Commerce?

Answer (score 0):

The name prefix options can be configured under:

*Store > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Name and Address Options*